# ASP.NET Page.Title not being set in code

Tags: asp.net, debugging, webforms

I have the following code:

```
<% string NewTitle = ""; %>
<%     
    if (Page.Title.ToLowerInvariant().Trim() == "home page")
    {
        NewTitle = "CCS LABS";
    }
    else
    {
        NewTitle = Page.Title + " - CCS LABS";
    }         
%>

<title> @NewTitle </title>
```

I am checking to see if the current age is the "Home Page" if it is, then I change the the title to "CCS LABS" - if it is not then I add " - CCS LABS" to the title and set the title to @NewTitle

When I break on the if statement the code recognises I am in the home page and sets NewTitle accordingly. However, it then jumps over the  section. The page is still titled "Home Page".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@var** is **razor** syntax. you cant use it in an **aspx** or **ascx** file.
Change you code to this:

```
<%  string NewTitle = "";     
    if (Page.Title.ToLowerInvariant().Trim() == "home page")
    {
        NewTitle = "CCS LABS";
    }
    else
    {
        NewTitle = Page.Title + " - CCS LABS";
    }         
%>

<title> <%= NewTitle %> </title>
```